# XZY transformation matrix to XYZ

Tags: math, matrix, rotation, quaternions

I have a transformation matrix from an application where the basis are XZY and I want to obtain this matrix into a system with XYZ basis. ¿Is it possible?

This is because i'm importing some 3D objects from an app in XZY basis and I want to rotate and translate them -but the axis here changed to XYZ-.

¿Could I have the quaternion of the rotation with the new basis?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a comment with the matrix that you used for your solution, as an aid to the rest of us coming up against this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 2 ways to go.

1. Simply swap Y <-> Z components of quaternion or rotation matrix.
2. Build transformation from one Basis to other and multiply current transformation. Transformation changing coordinate axes can be described with 4x4 matrix or 3x3 if only rotation used

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i did it in the second way, and it worked well :)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by a [basis transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis); however from your description exchanging of coordinates might be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked. Sorry but i haven't got enough reputation to vote the answer as useful.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the comment! Happy coding!